# How to get a zero Array2 copying dimension from another Array2

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

Just learning some rust. I'm using `ndarray` and I need to construct a zero matrix copying the dimension from another matrix. I tried

```
fn make_0(matrix: Array2<i32>) -> Array2<i32> {
        Array2::zeros(matrix.shape())
}
```

But this does not compile:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<&[usize] as ShapeBuilder>::Dim == Dim<[usize; 2]>`
   --> src/lib.rs:62:9
    |
62  |         Array2::zeros(matrix.shape())
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected array `[usize; 2]`, found struct `IxDynImpl`
    |
    = note: expected struct `Dim<[usize; 2]>`
               found struct `Dim<IxDynImpl>`
```

I can solve it with

```
fn make_0(matrix: Array2<i32>) -> Array2<i32> {
        Array2::zeros((matrix.shape()[0], matrix.shape()[1]))
}
```

But I guess there's something better and I'm lost with types here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for `ArrayBase::shape()`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.15.4/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.shape) recommends using `.raw_dim()` instead:

> Note that you probably don’t want to use this to create an array of the same shape as another array because creating an array with e.g. `Array::zeros()` using a shape of type `&[usize]` results in a dynamic-dimensional array. If you want to create an array that has the same shape and dimensionality as another array, use `.raw_dim()` instead:
>
> ```rust
> // To get the same dimension type, use `.raw_dim()` instead:
> let c = Array::zeros(a.raw_dim());
> assert_eq!(a, c);
> ```

So you probably want to do something like this:

```rust
fn make_0(matrix: Array2<i32>) -> Array2<i32> {
    Array2::zeros(matrix.raw_dim())
}
```